# how to read and display image from a BLE device to Android app?

Tags: android, image, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am currently working on a project where i have to read and display an jpeg image (taken from a TI CC2541 BLE powered camera device) on an Android app which i have to develop. Using the [official Android BLE Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) and some code online as reference i was able to setup and scan for the device. However, i got stuck when it come to setting up the GATT profile(services and characteristics) in order to do the image transferring from the device to my Android app. Anybody has any idea on how can i go about this? any link or guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: It might help to use apps like [BLE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner) to view the services and characteristics on the device.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your meant to use BLE to get the image?  It's not designed for big transfers like this, the performance will be very slow if this is the way you have to go.  Are you sure it's not got some classic Bluetooth support as well.

Comment: Take a look at the OAD profile, it has logic for transferring data to the BLE device. You could use the services structures and functionality as a base and tweak the code to transfer the data from the device. For example, instead of notifying the phone (central) with block index, notify with the block index and data. The central will write only next block index instead of block index and data.

Comment: It does make make sense to transfer a whole image using BLE, since it only can transmit 20 bytes at a time.